# Automatic rollback to last working revision for Cloud Run fully managed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I am planning to host my website frontend and API code to cloud run. I am deploying the code via
cloudbuild yml file. My concern is, I have seen that when we deploy cloud run app, and sometimes when
the app crashes, it server the traffic from that revision only. Results in website downtime.

Is there any way where new revision supposes say gives error and become faulty, so cloud run didn't
serve/switch traffic to that revision and rollback to previous/current working revision automatically.
I know we can switch/manage traffic between revision. But is there any condition we can put like, by
default it serves traffic from the latest revision but in case, the latest revision gets faulty, it
sticks/switch to current working revision.

I have gone through this doc for traffic management, but it doesn't answer my question  -

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration

I have used blue-green deployment pipeline before via jenkins, where I can put a condition, that
one instance didn't start, then switch the traffic to another one.

Please suggest if it is possible or what should be the ideal process for 0 downtime in case of faulty
revision automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The feature to do this *automatically* does not exist yet. However, we have a project in the works that lets you do automated rollouts and rollbacks based on telemetry signals. If you are interested trying it out once we have a beta, [fill out this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSehGqvPDTyObo6rfrtHj1h9GzuxuON-PRW35FCAguUNTPn9xw/viewform?usp=sf_link).

Until then, you can use the commands in your Jenkins or similar pipelines to switch traffic to each revision manually using the documentation link you have.

Comment: Thnx for the clarification, yeah,  I have already removed the Jenkins pipeline and currently looking for traffic switch via cloud run manually.

Comment: any news on this tool? sounds cool

Comment: @Hilikus it's offered as an experimental tool as it's not official.